# Extremely noisy FFT of a simple signal on Python

Tags: fft, python

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the FFT modules on Python. I'm thus doing some tests with simple functions, and I'm having troubles with the simplest one : the FFT of a sine. It is extremely noisy, and the full spectrum is very dependent on the sampling rate, with some sampling rates resulting in fairly big spectral features away from the frequency of my sine.

I am not very familiar with the limitations of the FFT. Is this to be expected, even with such a simple signal? If not, what am I doing wrong (I'm thinking there might be some rule I don't know about, e.g. the number of points should be a power of 2 or whatnot)?

Here is the FFT analysis of $\sin(2\pi ft)$ with $f = 10\, \text{kHz}$ (full spectrum above, zoomed between $0$ and $f + 3 \,\text{kHz}$ below) :

[image]

And here is the code I used :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = 10e3
start = 0
end = 100 * 1/f
ws = 2**18 # sample rate

N = int((end - start) * ws) # Number of points

# Define the time series
t = np.linspace(start, end, N, endpoint = False)

# Signal
sign = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

# FFT
freq_sign = np.fft.fftfreq(N, 1/ws)
fft_sign = np.fft.fft(sign)

# PLOT
fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(2, 1)

# Full spectrum
ax1.plot(freq_sign, fft_sign)

# Zoomed in around f
StIn = 0 # starting frequency index
EndIn = int((f + 3000)/(ws/N)) # end frequency index
ax2.plot(freq_sign[StIn:EndIn], fft_sign[StIn:EndIn])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Fourier transform of $\sin(2 \pi f t)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions,_one-dimensional) consists of two purely imaginary-valued impulses at $\pm f$. With that said, note the warning that appears when you run the code you provided:

```
numpy/core/_asarray.py:83: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

You are plotting the real part of the FFT output. Since the "correct" value is purely imaginary, all you're seeing is what's left due to the roundoff error inherent in the (double-precision) floating-point arithmetic. Change this lines:

```py
ax1.plot(freq_sign, fft_sign)
```

to

```py
ax1.plot(freq_sign, np.abs(fft_sign))
```

and

```
ax2.plot(freq_sign[StIn:EndIn], fft_sign[StIn:EndIn])
```

to

```
ax2.plot(freq_sign[StIn:EndIn], np.abs(fft_sign[StIn:EndIn]))
```

And you get the result you're probably looking for:

[image]

Comment: yeah, you were faster...

Comment: Thanks, that was a well-earned reminder about the phase of the FT of sine. For my defense, in most of my work I tend to care only about the amplitude of the FT, so it kinda went over my head, even though I found the amplitude fishy. 

In the same vein, why is the amplitude of each harmonic 1250, and not 1/2?

Comment: you need to divide the result by the the length of the input signal

Comment: Oh ok, I see they put the normalisation on the inverse FT, interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

Watch the magnitude of the plots: 10⁻¹¹. We can call that 0, for all practical purposes. Can you guess what's going wrong?

You must have dismissed this warning:

```
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return np.asarray(x, float)
```

So, what you're looking at is the real part of the DFT you've done!

But $\sin$ is an odd function. The Fourier transforms of odd real-valued functions are purely imaginary.

The noise you see is indeed numerical noise, caused by floating point accuracy during the calculation of the sine, and also (but probably to a lesser degree) during the FFT. Your plots should *actually* be zero, not only "very very close to zero".

Comment: I'll +1, just because you were a little slower doesn't mean you shouldn't get *some* credit ^^

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted @Jason R answer instead of yours as his was a bit more complete and offered the fixes for the script. I would just like to specify - because it might be an interesting warning for others - that on Spyder I get the warning once (when first running the script after opening Spyder), then never again after that.

Comment: that happens everywhere where the Python interpreter running your program lives on.

Comment: I will keep that in mind!